# Any way to determine which object called a method?

Tags: ruby, messaging, introspection, dynamic-languages

I'm hoping that Ruby's message-passing infrastructure means there might be some clever trick for this.

How do I determine the calling object -- which object called the method I'm currently in?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an option, there is a [`binding_of_caller` gem](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller) that allows you to execute code in context of any caller on the call stack (caller, caller's caller and so on). It's useful for inspecting (read *do anything at any position on the call stack*) call stack in development, as used in [`better_errors`](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors).

> Objects of class `Binding` encapsulate the execution context at some particular place in the code and retain this context for future use.
>
> – http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.4/Binding.html

Should I mention, **this technique should only be used for debugging, fun or educational purposes**, because it violates principles of OOP really badly.
Mostly because of `eval`.

Let's prepare stuff:

```
require 'binding_of_caller' # I assume, you installed this gem already?
```

Get the **immediate** (closest on stack, hence `0`) caller instance:

```
binding.of_caller(0).eval('self')
```

...or even an immediate calling method:

```
binding.of_caller(0).eval('__method__')
```

If you need to get higher up the call stack, use numbers other than `0` for getting a caller's binding.

Awfully hacky. But if you really need this — there you go.

Answer (score 16):

You can easily look at the line of code that called the function of interest through

```
caller.first
```

which will tell you the filename and line number which called the relevant function. You could then back-calculate which object it was.

However, it sounds like you're more after some object that called a certain function, perhaps within an instance method. I'm not aware of a method for figuring this out - but I wouldn't use it anyway, since it seems to violate encapsulation badly.

Comment: That's a really good point, I will just pass the calling object instead. The idea was to simplify some of the arguments to a method by automatically reflecting some information about the calling object.

Comment: well, ideally, if it's more than once, it should be a method in a superclass, and you can use `self`.

Answer (score 3):

Technology at its finest:

```
 1  # phone.rb
 2  class Phone
 3    def caller_id
 4      caller
 5    end
 6  end
 7  
 8  class RecklessDriver
 9    def initialize
10      @phone = Phone.new
11    end
12    def dial
13      @phone.caller_id
14    end
15  end
16  
17  p = Phone.new
18  p.caller_id.inspect   # => ["phone.rb:18:in `<main>'"]
19  
20  macek = RecklessDriver.new
22  macek.dial.inspect    # => ["phone.rb:13:in `dial'", "phone.rb:22:in `<main>'"]
```

**Note:** *Line number for demonstrative purposes.* `phone.rb:X` refers to Line `X` of the script.

Look at `phone.rb:13`! This `dial` method is what sent the call! And `phone.rb:22` refers to the reckless driver that used the `dial` method!

Answer (score 1):

You mean like `self`?

```
irb> class Object
  ..   def test
  ..     self
  ..   end
  .. end
  => nil
irb> o = Object.new
  => #<Object:0xb76c5b6c>
irb> o.test
  => #<Object:0xb76c5b6c>
```

Comment: ++ Dude, that's totally awesome how that looks like a stylized Z

Comment: I read the question that inside your `test()` OP wants to obtain the the object that you get if just type `self` in irb.

Answer (score 1):

Peter's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2703146/473040) used in production code example

In my company we were deprecating `deleted` flag in flavor of [Paranoia gem](https://github.com/rubysherpas/paranoia) `deleted_at` column. The code bellow is how we were ensuring all will go well before we remove column (deploying this code and then after 2 or 3 days of being live we deploy migration `remoove_column :lessons, :deleted`

```
class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base

  def deleted
    if caller.select { |c| c.match /serialization\.rb/ }.any?
      # this is Rails object mapping
      !!deleted_at
    else
      raise 'deplicated - deleted was replaced by  deleted_at'
    end
  end
end
```