# How to get the name of the calling method?

Tags: ruby

is there a way in Ruby to find the calling method name inside of a method?

For example:

```
class Test
  def self.foo
    Fooz.bar
  end
end

class Fooz
  def self.bar
    # get Test.foo or foo
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the name of the currently executing method in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199527/get-the-name-of-the-currently-executing-method-in-ruby)

Comment: get calling object: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703136/any-way-to-determine-which-object-called-a-method

Comment: Not a duplicate of "Get the name of the currently executed method in Ruby."  This question asks for the name of the calling method, not the name of the current method.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

```
puts caller[0]
```

or perhaps...

```
puts caller[0][/`.*'/][1..-2]
```

Comment: Yes, see Kernel#caller, aka http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Kernel.html#M001073

Comment: That gives the name of the calling method, but it doesn't give any indication to which module or class the method belongs to. Is that possible?

Comment: @thomthom Yes that is possible you can call self.class.name to see  the class name

Comment: Excellent use of regex as a string index!  Can also use `caller[0][/\`(.*)'/,1]`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Rails 5.2.1. In Rails controller this returns `"block in make_lambda"`. I guess this is for Ruby only.

Answer (score 189):

In Ruby 2.0.0, you can use:

```
caller_locations(1,1)[0].label
```

It's [much faster](http://blog.marc-andre.ca/2013/02/23/ruby-2-by-example/#caller_locations) than the Ruby 1.8+ solution:

```
caller[0][/`([^']*)'/, 1]
```

Will get included in `backports` when I get the time (or a pull request!).

Comment: It's worth noting that this is not available in Rubinius.

Comment: if ur using pry, you have to ignore the pry stacktrace it seems...there doesn't seem to be a default solution for that.

Comment: Now it seems to be `caller_locations[0].label` on Ruby 2.2.0 else you always have `send_action` result

Comment: how can we get only call app method and ignore frameworks call ?

Answer (score 40):

Use `caller_locations(1,1)[0].label` (for ruby >= 2.0)

**Edit**: My answer was saying to use `__method__` but I was wrong, it returns the current method name.

Comment: @OswaldoFerreira Thanks, found it on SO in another answer somewhere

Comment: This is incorrect, it returns current method, not the method that called the current method...

Comment: works like a charm. Also seem to be much faster than pre 2.0 methods.

Answer (score 21):

I use

```
caller[0][/`([^']*)'/, 1]
```

Comment: What's the advantage of this over DigitalRoss' approach?

Comment: Cleaner and more precise.  Rather than doing the search, then using an array method to split of unwanted characters based on position (which could be incorrect).

Comment: Why not simply use caller[0][/`(.*)'/, 1] ? I'm not a guru about regular expressions, but it seems to work.

Comment: @collimarco As long as the String doesn't contain a `'` beyond the one you're looking for (and I assume it can't), the result will be the same, sure. However, `[^']*` will perform  better as the regex engine will stop trying to match that part the expression the moment it reaches a `'` (your version will go to the end, then backtrack because it didn't find a `'` at the end). The difference is pretty negligible in this case of course, but it's a good habit to avoid `.` in regexes where possible.

Answer (score 4):

How about

```
caller[0].split("`").pop.gsub("'", "")
```

Much cleaner imo.

Answer (score 4):

Instead you can write it as library function and make a call wherever needed. The code goes as follows :

```
module CallChain
  def self.caller_method(depth=1)
    parse_caller(caller(depth+1).first).last
  end

  private

  # Copied from ActionMailer
  def self.parse_caller(at)
    if /^(.+?):(\d+)(?::in `(.*)')?/ =~ at
      file   = Regexp.last_match[1]
      line   = Regexp.last_match[2].to_i
      method = Regexp.last_match[3]
      [file, line, method]
    end
  end
end
```

To trigger the above module method you need to call like this:
`caller = CallChain.caller_method`

[code reference from](http://grosser.it/2009/07/01/getting-the-caller-method-in-ruby/)

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: @XaviLópez have updated the answer, plz rectify if am doing wrong or somthing mistaken...thnx for the kind suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks for improving your answer. Unfortunately, I don't have enough knowledge about Ruby to be able to properly comment about this post, but the answer looks alright now. I've removed my downvote. Best luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @amitkarsale works, but `private` does not do anything in a module since modules are not instantiated. Here is `call_chain.rb`, rewritten according to Rubocop's suggestions:

```rb
module CallChain
  def self.caller_method(depth = 1)
    parse_caller(caller(depth + 1).first).last
  end

  def self.parse_caller(at)
    return unless /^(.+?):(\d+)(?::in `(.*)')?/ =~ at

    file   = Regexp.last_match[1]
    line   = Regexp.last_match[2].to_i
    method = Regexp.last_match[3]
    [file, line, method]
  end
end

if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME
  caller = CallChain.caller_method
  puts caller
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the caller and callee information in any language, whether it be ruby or java or python, you would always want to look at the stack trace. In some languages, such as Rust and C++, there are options built into the compiler to turn on some sort of profiling mechanism you can view during run time. I do belive one exists for Ruby called ruby-prof.

And as mentioned above, you could look into the execution stack for ruby. This execution stack is an array containing backtrace location objects.

Essentially all you need to know about this command is as follows:

caller(start=1, length=nil) → array or nil