# Calling method Ruby1.9

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

Similar to `__callee__`, is there something which returns the calling method?  I realize there is the `caller` which I amble to strip the name of the caller method from but I am curious is there is a standard method for returning the name of the calling method without any other information along with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in MRI. But there are some alternatives.

In case you happen to use Rubinius, you can do this instead of parsing `caller`:

```
Rubinius::VM.backtrace(1, false).first.name
#=> :calling_method_name
```

You can also [use a gem to parse](https://github.com/Asher-/sender) the result of `caller` for you. It should work for any Ruby > 1.9.

[The answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100299/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-method-in-ruby) describes how you can do some simple parsing yourself.

And finally, there appears to be [work in progress](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/3917) on getting a feature like this into Ruby 2.0, although the relevant ticket has not been updated for a while.

Comment: The `sender` gem that you link looks very important.