# Finding the caller method in Ruby

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the name of the calling method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100299/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-method)

I have a method `#foo`. That method can be called from many places (scopes). I need `#foo` to find out where it was called from. But not the stack trace (like what `#caller` returns), I want the pure name of the method (like what `#__callee__` returns). Does a method for this exist in Ruby?

Comment: Not a built-in method, but there's a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100299/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-method-in-ruby

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's not so bad to use it like that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `__method__`. Place that in any method body and it should provide the name of the method. And you can always fetch the context by using `.class` or `.class.ancestors`.

Comment: Hmm, it seems like `__method__` returns the same as `__callee__` (the name of the current scope). I want the previous scope. So, if `#bar` called `#foo`, I want a method that I can call from `#foo` which would return `"bar"`