# Get what method called current method

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get the name of the calling method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100299/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-method)

How do I tell what method called foo in the following example?

```
class Example
  def initialize
  end

  def foo
    puts "Hello World"  
  end

  def bar
    foo 
  end

  def cats
    bar      
  end
end
```

Example.new.cats prints bar. I am trying to get the whole callstack. E.g. cats -> bar -> foo

**Update:**

This works: puts caller[0..1]

```
Hello World
(irb):11:in `bar'
(irb):15:in `cats'
```

Comment: should be decided at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use for instance: `puts caller[0]` This will give you info for the caller.

Comment: This works for the last method, but does not show me the entire callstack. Example.new.cats will print bar. I am looking for something like "cats -> bar -> foo"

Comment: How about `puts caller[0..1]`?

Comment: caller[0..1] works! Thank you :)

Comment: To get a full trace do caller[0..(caller.length-1)]