# Find which method called current method in a model with ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I need to find which method called "abc", based on that I can do some operations.

```
Class A
  def method1
   abc
  end

  def method2
   abc
  end

  def abc
   puts "abc" if calling_method == :method1
   puts "xyz" 
  end
end
```

Is this possible in ruby?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the name of the calling method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100299/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-method)

Comment: Sorry Sawa, I tried to find the question but could not find It. I got my answer from the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `caller()` method.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller

Comment: thanks for your effort, I got the answer from the link provided by @sawa. +1 from my side.

Comment: @AbibullahRahamathulah,y eah it's a much better link.