# ruby metaprogramming method name

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I try to get the name of the method from which current method is called

```
def first_method
  my_method
end

def second_method
  my_method
end

def my_method
  puts "called from: #{method_name}"
end
```

and expected output:

"called from: first_method"

"called from: last_method"

Comment: see this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100299/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def a
  c
end
def b
  c
end
def c
  p caller
end

a
#=> ["/Users/phrogz/Desktop/tmp.rb:2:in `a'", "/Users/phrogz/Desktop/tmp.rb:11:in `<main>'"]
b
#=> ["/Users/phrogz/Desktop/tmp.rb:5:in `b'", "/Users/phrogz/Desktop/tmp.rb:12:in `<main>'"]
```

You can use a regular expression like `` caller[0][/`(.+?)'/,1] `` to match the name in the first one.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15098459/405017) has a much better solution for Ruby 2.0+

See also: https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller