# Get and write caller method name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to know what method updates my object. I have ActiveRecord class `Event`, with column `method_name` in it. Is there some way to save caller method in that column after my object was updated?

Update

I though about something like this:

```
class Event
  after_save :set_caller

  def set_caller
    self.update(method_name: caller)
  end
end
```

But at this moment caller is `active_support/callbacks.rb`

Comment: You know how to get caller method name. You also know (presumably) how to update an activerecord object. What's the problem here?

Comment: One method saves your object, and that method in turn, calls another method to save your object, and the chain may be even longer. What would method do you want to save at the end? The first one or the last one?

Comment: You might use [`after_commit`](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/da840d13da865331297d5287391231b1ed39721b) callback to get [`#caller`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) and store it somewhere.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, the thing is that i don't know how to get caller method name

Comment: @yozzz: easy. Just use `caller` method! It'll return a stack trace. You probably only want the first line. It contains file/line info too, so you'll want to extract method name from it with regex or something

Comment: @mudasobwa: won't `caller` in `after_commit` show just 200 lines of AR internals?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Good point. It likely will. Hmmm. Will check :)

Comment: @yozzz: "But at this moment caller is active_support/callbacks.rb" - obviously. Because it's a callback. Called by ActiveRecord. Use `caller` in `update` or `save` or whichever method you use to save an object

Comment: @SergioTulentsev about example that I provide, as you say it returns over 200 lines of AR internals and others methods

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i understand, but there so many places, that can update object. I can miss something...

Comment: If you control the calling code, you should know all the methods you use. Also here's a tip: in output of `caller`, skip all the AR stuff and find the first line from your app files. It'll likely be the caller you need.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Yes, filtering by `/\A#{Rails.root}/` does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

> the  thing is that i don't know how to get caller method name

[How to get the name of the calling method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100299/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-method)

You could use

```
caller[0][/`.*'/][1..-2]
```