# Get method name that called validator in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a controller with a method

```
def create
   if passenger.valid?
   ....
end
```

In my Passenger model I have my validation rules. Those rules depend on from which method the validator has been called.

So the question is, how can I get inside my model the name method that called the validator, in this case `'create'`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the name of the calling method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5100299/how-to-get-the-name-of-the-calling-method)

Comment: This does not solve my question since it only returns the path of the model.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to rephrase the question as either getting the caller name OR ways to implement conditional validation, rather than combining the two.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
caller_locations(1,1)[0].label
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest setting an `attr_accessor` in the model for this case

```
# In model
attr_accessor :validation_caller

def valodation_rules
  if @validation_caller.eql?('create')
    # validations
  else
    # validations
  end
end

# in controller
model_instance.validation_caller = 'create'
```

Hope it helps..