# Check if method calls itself Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec

I am testing this method:

```
  def get_input
    print "Pick a column (0-6):\n"
    valid_input?(gets) || get_input
  end
```

How can i test if the `get_input` method is called from inside itself? because if i use

```
describe '#get_input' do
    subject(:game_input) { described_class.new(1, 2) }
    it 'sends get_input when input is invalid' do
      allow(game_input).to receive(:valid_input?).and_return(false)
      expect(game_input).to receive(:get_input)
      game_input.get_input
  end
```

it passes the test regardless since `get_input` is called first anyways.

I want to test if `get_input` is called from within itself, and not continue looping when i give it an invalid input in the test.

Something like:

```
I set valid_input? to return false in my test
I check if get_input is called on game_input, but only from inside the get_input method
```

Any help is appreciated

Also im completely new to RSpec so sorry for any stupid questions

Comment: You'd likely want to check the number of times `get_input` is called (and provide enough return values for `valid_input?` to match). Unrelated, but a recursive function like this, while clean, isn't necessarily the best approach; IRL it's just a way for someone to crash the game.

Comment: Something like this?

    `it 'sends get_input when input is invalid' do
      allow(game_input).to receive(:valid_input?).and_return(false, true)
      expect(game_input).to receive(:valid_input?).twice
      game_input.get_input
    end`

also thanks for the tip, should i use a loop instead?

Comment: You could also check out the `Kernel#caller` https://stackoverflow.com/a/5100339/7619578 , https://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/caller , https://reinteractive.com/posts/399-dissecting-code-with-ruby-s-caller-method

Comment: @Skauen I don't recall the exact syntax, but that's the right idea. *I* would use a loop, but that doesn't mean it's right ;)

Comment: Isn’t the recursion an implementation detail? The method could achieve the same behavior with a loop. Maybe you can find a more robust approach to test your method if you don’t focus on the recursion.

Comment: @Stefan I acutally started with a loop, but thought it would be easier to test if `get_input` was sent again, rather than testing the loop (again, im new to this). But i can see how recursion can cause the app to crash if someone tries.

Comment: With _"more robust approach"_ I mean the test. Instead of checking for recursion you could check whether the user is prompted again after providing invalid input. This way, you'd test the method's behavior instead of its implementation.

Comment: @Stefan Thats what I ended up doing. Makes more sense now.