# How to pass `self` when invoking a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming

I have a method that sends a message when it triggers something. The signature is:

```
Sender.send(user, message_id, source)
```

The usage scenario is in the callbacks in active model. When some model is verified, we send a message through the template:

```
after_save if: 'verified_changed? && verified' do
    Sender.send(user, :verified, self) # pass self as the template parameter
end
```

We pass `self`. There are some solutions to make invoking simple as below:

```
after_save if: 'verified_changed? && verified' do
    Sender.send(user, :verified) # not need to pass self, guess it when invoking
end
```

Is there a method that passes `self` when a method is invoked?

More concrete examples are below:

```
#define a method, return the environment self
def guess
end

guess #=> main

class A
    guess #=> A
    def a
        guess
    end
end

A.new.a #=> #<A:0x000000026cd2f0>
```

I share my send method below (In class `Sender`):

```
def send(*users, id, source = self)
  desc = source.class.to_s
  text = "There is a new process in your #{desc}: #{id}"
  users.reject{|user| user.nil?}.each do |user|
    send_message(user, tag: 'Process', text: text)
    send_mail(user, subject: text, text: text)
    send_sms(user, text: text)
  end
end
```

Comment: yes we can achieve this by implementing method with default params change `send` method definition like `def send(user, verified, obj=self)`. Share your send method code then i can give a proper answer below.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli: try this. `self` will not be the caller's `self`.

Comment: I think the default self argument is a perfect solution. Thank you all. However, it seems a subtle place in my method declaration.

Comment: @Run: I kinda doubt that this approach will work for you. `self` there will be `Caller`, not whatever you actually wanted. http://pastie.org/10781838

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703136/any-way-to-determine-which-object-called-a-method

Comment: In object oriented programming, the method execution should be independed of the caller. So if you want to pass self, you should just do it explicitly. As bonus, it is easier to test.

Comment: Maybe there are some changes in ruby 2.3, the output is not the expected one.