# Accessing column stored in a join table - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

I have a join table called `ProductFeatures` which joins `Product` and `Feature` instances via `has_many: ..., through: product_features`, and has an additional column called `rating`.

I want to add `.rating` method on `Feature` which will return a rating float based on specific product instance that is calling it. Something like:

```
Product.find(...).features.first.rating #=> should specific product_feature rating
```

I've tried:

- passing caller_id as an argument to `.rating`. This works, but makes me use product.id each time I want to get a specific product rating feature.
- [Obtaining a caller instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2703136/any-way-to-determine-which-object-called-a-method) id from inside the method using `.caller` (with [binding_of_caller](https://github.com/banister/binding_of_caller), or vanilla Ruby), but `.caller` does not seem to let me get a calling instance id, and would also fail in tests as the caller would be the spec's `ExampleGroup`

Comment: Do you use `has_and_belongs_to_many` or `has_many :through`?

Comment: @MichałMłoźniak `has_many :through`

Comment: So why not just use `product_features` association for this: `p = Product.find(...); p.product_features.first.rating`?

Comment: @MichałMłoźniak that's the goal. but how do I get the product instance id inside Feature's `rating` method? Say my query is something like `product.features.first.rating`. Then inside the Rating class, I'd have something like `def rating; ProductFeature.find_by(feature_id: feature.id, product_id ???).rating`, right?

Comment: What I am suggesting is not to add `rating` method to `Feature` class, but just use `product_features` association. Perhaps you can somehow implement this, but it will make your code harder to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can get these data with other way.

> - I want to add `#rating` method on Feature which will return a rating
>     float based on specific product instance that is calling it. Something
>     like:

```
## Controller add this code snipped
   get_feature = Product.find(...).features
   rating(get_feature)

   protected

   def rating(get_all_feature)
     all_rating = []
     get_all_feature.each do |feature|
       all_rating <<  feature.product_features.each { |u| u.rating }
     end
     all_rating
   end
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: thanks! thing is, I want to pull a specific rating. The above will return a collection of `ProductFeature` instances where the feature_id matches self.id.

Comment: Same problem. This returns a collection, while a feature.rating should be pulled from ProductFeatures.rating. That's why `.rating` is added to the join table so that its unique per `product.feature`